# SSH command execution/variable substitution issue

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, centos7

I was trying to execute a `ssh` command and I see it takes environment variable from the host (local) machine rather than the machine I `ssh` into (remote server).

Example:

```sh
firstuser@remote> ssh testuser@remote echo ${USER}
firstuser
```

It was expecting it to echo ***testuser*** instead of ***firstuser*** as it is the username I connected with.

If it can help, I am using CentOS7.

Any thoughts/explanations on this specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you are getting the variable `${USER}` from the host (*local*) machine not from the SSH (*remote*) server. This is because you are executing it all in one command. Your command is being processed locally - meaning the variable is being substituted - before being sent to the remote (SSH) server.

You can solve this by passing the command as a string that will not be translated/processed/substituted locally to, in your case,  `firstuser`, or whichever other previously declared variable.

```sh
firstuser@mymachine> ssh testuser@mymachine 'echo ${USER}'
```

Important note here is that `echo ${USER}` is in **single quotes**, it **will not work with double quotes**. This is basic *bash*/shell rule but as a courtesy, you can find out more about this at https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/shell-tools/#shell-scripting

In a nutshell, when a variable is being processed/interpreted/substituted *locally* as you are trying to do, the remote SSH server receives the litteral: `echo firstuser` not `echo ${USER}`, which would be processed remotely, as intended.

Comment: With or without double quotes, you can use `echo \$USER`. Either way, the point is to get the variable sent to the server for expansion.

Comment: I have to agree with the answer proposed. The problem is, in your case, that the variable is being processed locally before it is sent to the remote server. This causes whatever variable to be echoed as is was processed locally. Try putting your command in single quote, as said. This way, it will be processed by the remote server instead of locally.